# Wordpress deprecated, comments issue

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, deprecated

Basiclly, this is my index.php code:

```
<?php 
    get_header();
?>      
        <!-- WRAPPER START -->
        <section id="wrapper">
            <!--  START DYNAMIC PART -->
            <?php 
                if(have_posts()):
                    while(have_posts()):
                        the_post();
            ?>
            <!-- MAIN CONTENT START-->
            <section id="main-content">

                <!-- SIDEBAR START -->
                <aside id="tab-lists">
                    <?php if(!dynamic_sidebar('telerik-sidebar')): ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if(!dynamic_sidebar('telerik-sidebar2')): ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </aside>    
                <!-- SIDEBAR END -->

                <!-- BIG POST START -->
                <div id="big-post">
                    <article>
                        <header>
                            <h2>
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </h2>
                            <p class="post-info">
                                Posted by <?php the_author(); ?> in on <?php the_date('d-m-Y'); ?> | <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php comments_number( 'no comment', 'one comment', '% comments' ); ?></a>
                            </p>
                        </header>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        <div class="post-text">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>     
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <!-- BIG POST END -->
                <div id="com">
                    <?php 
                        comments_template('',true); 
                    ?>
                </div>
            </section>
            <!-- MAIN CONTENT END -->
            <?php 
                endwhile;
                endif;
            ?>
            <!-- END DYNAMIC PART -->
        </section>
        <!-- WRAPPER END -->
<?php 
    get_footer();
?>
```

It worked perfect on my localhost, but when I uploaded it into wordpress I get the `Notice: Theme without comments.php is deprecated since version 3.0 with no alternative available. Please include a comments.php template in your theme. in /f5/funkz/public/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2670` - error, so i made a comments.php, and put the just my `comments_template('',true);` in there (in php tags) and on his place in the index.php i placed `comments_template();` to call the file, but then i get memory issue error...I read in some places that can be resolved by increasing it in `php.ini` , but I didn't find it in my server's folders :( . If you have a solution thank you in advance.

Comment: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4864 bytes) in /f5/funkz/public/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 915` This is the memory issue i get.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
<?php comments_template( '/templates/comments.php', true );     ?>
```

and move comments.php in to dir templates.

Comment: 0
down vote
 

Just use comments_template( '/templates/comments.php', true );

and move comments.php in to dir templates.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the 2012 `comments.php` template, make sure that it is not looking from the line:

```
@package Wordpress, @subpackage TwentyTwelve @since v1.0.
```